# TypeScript testing -- access to static assets?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a CLI application written in TypeScript. It builds, using `tsc`, transpiling to JS in a `build` directory. I have tests to test the code involved in the CLI app. Those tests require access to static assets. TSC transpiles my TypeScript code to JS, and puts it in the `build` directory.

Once it's in that `build` directory, I can't figure out how to give the code access to the static assets needed for testing. Obviously, relative paths based on the TS files don't do me much good. `__dirname` resolves to the directory of the compiled JS files, and not the directory of the original TS files, so that doesn't help.

I don't want to do something that makes no sense pre-transpilation (but works post-transpilation), but I can't figure out a way for this asset access to make sense in both situations. I can't be the first person to run into this. Is there some magic token I should know about?

Comment: With process.cwd() you can get the root dir, where the node process was called. Or do you call your entry.js from inside build?

Comment: Well I usually have the assets in the a /<root>/assets path and the source in /<root>/src and the compiled files in /<root>/<compiled> so paths like `__dirname/../assets/...` work from both places. I know it's not an elegant solution but it's a solution

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a way to make this work without relying on "magic" like the relative paths being coincidentally the same for both the TS and transpired JS files. Am I wrong? Python compiles `*.py` files to `*.pyc` files in another directory and somehow manages to get this all correct.

Comment: @SamuelKnoch ...but `npm test` can be invoked from anywhere in the source tree, no? So you can't really count on the `cwd()` being the root of the project, right?

Comment: @ipmcc usually not npm test should always be called from the root, were also the package.json is located